# Does halo:master chief collection have online co-op campaign?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

Does halo: the master chief collection have online co-op campaign for all of the halo games. Could I play the halo 1 campaign online with a friend?

Answer (score 5):

You may play the Halo 1+2 campaigns online as 2 player co-op. Halo MCC is playable online.

**Edit as of December 2019:**

You may play all the Halo campaigns online alone or up to four other player in online Co-Op. Halo MCC is playable online with co-op and Multiplayer.